# Best practice for DateTime <--> DateTimeOffset

Tags: datetime, automapper, datetimeoffset

Right now in my code I have the following:

```
cfg.CreateMap<DateTimeOffset, DateTime>().ConstructUsing(x => x.UtcDateTime);
cfg.CreateMap<DateTime, DateTimeOffset>().ConstructUsing(x => new DateTimeOffset(x));
```

To say the least, this feels like a hack/kludge.  Is there a better and/or more standard way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second map is not needed, you can remove it.

Comment: I would not create such a map at all.  Use `DateTime` where you need it.  Use `DateTimeOffset` where you need it.  They are different things.  Mapping them as equivalent would be like mapping a customer and a boat - they may both have names, but they're very different creatures! ;)